# Maya, Dynamic constraint

Tags: python, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import math
def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(a[0]-b[0],2)+math.pow(a[1]-b[1],2)+math.pow(a[2]-b[2],2))
for i in range (1,50):
    cmds.currentTime(i)
    a=cmds.nParticle('nParticle1',id=0,q=1,attribute='position')
    b=cmds.nParticle('nParticle2',id=0,q=1,attribute='position')
    if dist(a,b)<1:
        cmds.select('nParticle1.pt[0]',tgl=True)
        cmds.select('nParticle2.pt[0]',tgl=True)
        mel.eval('createNConstraint pointTopoint 0;')
        break
```

the above code is executed after making two nParticles (with a single particle in each of them) and set the force field generation to a negative value in both of them so that they attract.

The problem is, i want to create a dynamic constraint when they are very close. But maya doesn't evaluates that until I go to frame 1. I need to evaluate the results without going to frame 1 and continue to the last frame.

Comment: Why not create the constraint before starting and then set an expression that turns on the constraint based on distances?

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it works only for frame 1. I have checked that.